# Error MSB4018: The "ResolveSdks" monodevelop

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.android, monodevelop

i had the following error in monodevelop:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Novell\Novell.MonoDroid.Common.targets(2,2): Error MSB4018: The "ResolveSdks" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2, String path3)
   at Novell.MonoDroid.Build.Tasks.ResolveSdks.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult) (MSB4018) (test)
```

how can i fix it?
to change the version doesn't works

Comment: as i am facing the same issue .is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You unistall jdk7 and jdk8 and install jdk 6